# Call logical database via Function Module?

Tags: abap, function-module, sap-hr

Is there a function Module to call a logical Database via function module or classes?

In my case I would need PNPCE, so it is the HCM Module.

Comment: Personally I avoid dealing with LDBs whenever possible. They were declared obsolete decades ago, and for good reason. Most of the time it's pretty simple to build a view to  replace them with. Especially now with the more powerful CDS views. Could you elaborate on why exactly you need this? Perhaps there is a better way to achieve that goal.

Comment: I do too. But sometimes I've got requirements from customers to use them and I can't get around this. Once I've been in a company and I developed a custom report and didn't use the LDB ( even though it was a requirement ). Authorization-Checks and data selection was all fine, but they wanted that I use the LDB because their developers only work with them. So I needed to change my report. Since then it happend quite a lot. This is why I am working with it, at least when needed...

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You can use the function module LDB_PROCESS.

Here the [SAP documentation](https://help.sap.com/doc/abapdocu_750_index_htm/7.50/en-US/abenldb_usage_function.htm).

But remember, LDB are obsolete.

Comment: Thanks! I think it is not really possible to call the selection screen via FM, is it? I know they are obsolete, but sometimes I must use them, because of customer wants / requires them, just one of a few disadvantages of the HCM-module. Most of the developers are old fashioned and don't want to use new and "fancy" techniques like CDS.. at least those who I know.

Comment: @Sasku If you want the selection screen, then why don't you create an executable program which is based on this logical database and you call this program instead of `LDB_PROCESS`?

Comment: @Sandra: some ldbs offer good selection screens, but as it is said in the answer they are obsolete. But if I don't need to use the selection but want the screen I would be able to have the best of 2 worlds (selection screen of ldb and my selection). It's just that I am lazy and don't want to build the screen over and over again or if I want to build a transaction only with the use of classes. Then I call a function module ( yeah I know I could just build one) which has the dynpro included. So there are use cases. But my original question is solved with the fm ldb_process

Answer (score -1):

LDBs are not obsolete, at least for HCM.  They are a fast, object-oriented, way to access HR data and are an advantage, not a disadvantage.  SAP have changed CDS views so now the earlier latest and greatest CDS stuff is now not supported.  The HCM LDBs still work with an ECC on premises system.  There are real business and technical reasons why your customers are requiring HR LDBs, e.g., consistency of selection screens, built-in authorizations, different selection screen or customer specific selection screens (HR report classes) to name just a few.  Your customers are not just being luddites and unless new to SAP know their own systems better than we do.

BTW, you can call screens from function modules, but not yet from methods (at least on my SAP release).

Comment: LDBs are also obsolete in the HCM-Module. In principal your arguments are correct, consistency, authorizations, etc. are totally valid, but it doesn't change the fact that they are obsolete.

Comment: Agree and disagree.  Customer created LDBs (were there ever really any?) are obsolete to create new ones, yes.  Using SAP LDBs are fine and IMO a safer and more elegant solution than programming your own DB reads.  SAP still uses LDBs in their own standard programs even in an S4/HANA on premises system.  I will rephrase that the HCM PNPCE LDB is not obsolete "for me" and it is a much better object-oriented solution than programming from scratch.